# how to handle response contents by AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

for me it seems impossible but expecting clarification on it.  i am sending a `request` as follow :

```
 <form action="/name" method="get">
     <input type="text" />
     <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

Now action class at server side manipulates & send the `response` to client, can i handle this `response` by `ajax` somehow ??

Comment: I don't understand. At which point to do want to use Ajax? You probably need to use Ajax from the start, and not send the form at all

Comment: Read this: [jquery.ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)... Might become helpful.

Comment: @Pekka i only want to handle the same `response` which is already send by _<form>_ submit button

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You either make a request through Ajax from the start (as shown by @Bozho), or you make a traditional GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to submit it via ajax (XmlHttpRequest) in order to be able to get the response that way.

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes this simple:

```
$.post("/name", {param:param}, function(data) {

});
```

In that example you should pass manually each form field as param. In case of bigger forms this is not that good. So you can use serialize():

```
$.post($("#yourForm").attr("action"),
       $("#yourForm").serialize(),
       responseHandlerFunction);
```

Comment: no no, there are some issue with `XmlHttpRequest` so i can not use to send  request via `ajax`

Comment: everyone on the web uses XmlHttpRequest, so I bet there are no serious issue that should stop you from doing so

Comment: can we send request this file type data `<input type="file />"` using _XmlHttpRequest_

Comment: type="file" is a bit special, but yes, you can.

Comment: as far i know, it's not possible to send `type="file"` using _XmlHttpRequest_ .  please let me know if you have any idea on it